How to set proxy on invoke-webrequest
I have the below script to install a defender software on my development server and when I run it I run into a error where "defender.ps1 is not recognized and err : invalid token"I feel like it needs proxy passed in the script to reach the internet, can someone help me with how I can pass proxy here in this script and if I am missing any syntax here?
$parameters = @{ 
    Uri = "https://us-east1.cloud.twistlock.com/us-2-158262581/api/v1/scripts/defender.ps1"
    Method = "Post"
    Headers = @{
        "authorization" = "Bearer <bearer token goes here>" 
    } 
    OutFile = "defender.ps1"
} 

if ($PSEdition -eq 'Desktop') { 
    Add-Type "
    using System.Net; 
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy { 
        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) { 
            return true;
        } 
    }" 
    
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
}
else { 
    $parameters.SkipCertificateCheck = $true
} 

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Invoke-WebRequest @parameters

.\defender.ps1 -type dockerWindows -consoleCN us-east1.cloud.twistlock.com -install

Invoke-WebRequest @parameters; .\defender.ps1 -type dockerWindows -consoleCN us-east1.cloud.twistlock.com -install -proxy http://outproxy-dev.com:3128

Is defender.ps1 located in the same folder as the script you've posted? You can do & $PSScriptRoot\defender.ps1 ... in place of .\defender.ps1 ...
